# How do I delete all the sub-lists from a list?

Tags: prolog

I would like to remove from a list of lists all the lists containing `[['One', _], _]`. I created the following clause, `delete_all`, that always works, except for my case:

```
delete_all(_,[],[]) :- !.
delete_all(X,[X|Tail],List) :-
    !,
    delete_all(X,Tail,List).
delete_all(X,[A|Tail],[A|List]) :-
    delete_all(X,Tail,List).
```

Example: (this works well)

```
?- delete_all(3,[3,4,3,5,3],K).
K = [4, 5] .
```

but this works poorly:

```
delete_all([['One', _], _], [[['One', 'Six'], 94],
    [['One', 'Ten'], 13], [['Two', 'Nine'], 35]], Y).
Y = [[['One', 'Ten'], 13], [['Two', 'Nine'], 35]].
```

Why does it delete only the first element? What could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, to test, here is a working one:

```
delete_all(E, L, R) :- findall(X, (member(X, L), X \= E), R).
```

I think your code doesn't works because it *instantiates* X, then inhibits further matches.The documentation for [delete](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=delete/3)/3 (that does what you're after, just swapping arguments) states the problem clearly enough.

You should change your first clause

```
delete_all(X,[E|Tail],List):-
    \+ X \= E, !, delete_all(X,Tail,List).
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem lies in the fact that your first term (the pattern you are searching for) contains variables and those variables `[unify](http://www.learnprolognow.org/lpnpage.php?pagetype=html&pageid=lpn-htmlse5)' with the list elements as you scan the list. Once you've passed an element that matches, the variables inside your pattern get instantiated to the values of the corrisponding terms in that element preventing from further matching.

A possible solution is to check if your pattern and your elements are [unifiable](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=unifiable/3) but not unifying them in the end.

Something like this could suits your needs:

```
delete_all(_,[],[]):-!.

delete_all(X,[H|Tail],List):-
    unifiable(X, H, _),
    !,
    delete_all(X,Tail,List).

delete_all(X,[A|Tail],[A|List]):-
    delete_all(X,Tail,List).
```

If you are using Yap, you will have to import the [library(terms)](http://www.dcc.fc.up.pt/~vsc/Yap/documentation.html#Terms).

```
:- use_module(library(terms)).
```

Another solution could be to use the tricky `not(not(X = H))` instead of `unifiable`, it does check if you can unify H and X, if you can the inner not prevents instantiation and the second one returns true.

UPDATE: as CapelliC has added, `\+ X \= E` is equal to `not(not(X = E))` but with a now more standard syntax.